# How can I change the color of a (Telerik) RadRibbonBar's title text?

Tags: wpf, telerik-radribbonbar

I've declared a Telerik `RadRibbonBar` in my application, but the title window's text is white, and looks like this:

[image]

In my opinion, it looks pretty bad. Does anyone know of any way to change it?
This is the XAML I'm using:

```
<telerikRibbon:RadRibbonWindow x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"                   
                               xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"                   
                               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                   
                               xmlns:telerik="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"                   
                               xmlns:telerikRibbon="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.RibbonBar"                                                 
                               Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <telerikRibbon:RadRibbonBar ApplicationName="This text is white and looks awful." DockPanel.Dock="Top" Focusable="False">
            <telerikRibbon:RadRibbonBar.ApplicationMenu>
                <telerikRibbon:ApplicationMenu>
                    <telerikRibbon:RadRibbonButton Text="New"/>
                </telerikRibbon:ApplicationMenu>
            </telerikRibbon:RadRibbonBar.ApplicationMenu>

            <telerikRibbon:RadRibbonTab Header="Home">

            </telerikRibbon:RadRibbonTab>
        </telerikRibbon:RadRibbonBar>

        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="White">
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</telerikRibbon:RadRibbonWindow>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you'll want to do is extract the template for RadRibbonBar to make a slight modification to a few Foreground properties.  Once extracted, look for:

PART_ActualWindowTitle

Which covers the Title you're seeing.  Under that search for the section with three textblocks (Title, Divider, ApplicationName) and change the XAML to something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock x:Name="Title" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"/>
<TextBlock x:Name="Divider"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="RibbonBarWindowTitleDivider" Text=" - "><Run Text=" - "/></TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationName"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding ApplicationName}"/>
```

Which will allow you to set your `<telerik:RadRibbonBar Foreground="ColorYouWant" />` and that will be reflected in the Title bar.  You can of course switch this to use a hard coded value, a resource from somewhere else in your app, etc., but this is the area you'll want to work with to have an impact on the application title.